# Is " just" necessary in this example?

Tags: grammar

If I say : " my hair is still wet because I have washed it", is it clear that the washing of the hair was a recent event or do I have to add "just"? To me the fact that the hair is still wet makes it clear that I washed it only a short while ago. Someone told me if I don't add " just", it could mean I washed my hair at some indefinite time in the past. I find this very strange, because like I said before, the fact that the hair is still wet is prove of recent action. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I notice that you are not simply explaining why your hair *is* wet, you have said that your hair is *still wet*. Including the word "still" makes the whole statement about explaining not just *why* it is wet, but *why it hasn't yet dried*.

If your intended meaning is that you literally just finished washing your hair then I think the sentence should omit the word "still" and include the word "just":

> My hair is wet because I have just washed it.

This shows that your hair is currently wet and explains that is the case because you only just washed it. The sentence doesn't sound right with both words in it, because "still" implies that some time has passed whereas inclusion of the word "just" implies that it has literally just happened.

If you include "still" but omit "just":

> My hair is *still* wet from washing it.

Rather than stating that you only just finished washing your hair, this suggests that it was washed fairly recently as it has not yet had enough time to dry out.

I wouldn't say that having wet hair alone negates the need to say that you *just* washed it. How long does hair take to dry? Half an hour? Long hair can stay damp for hours. Saying you "just" washed it implies that you literally just finished it. Saying that it is "still wet" allows for a longer period of time.

If you do not need to make any comment on timing, either to remark that your hair is taking a long time to dry, or suggest the time you washed it, then simply say "*my hair is wet because I washed it*".

Comment: But is it clear the washing took place fairly recently ( like the same day) and not sometime in my life like that person was suggesting as in : I have washed my hair sometime in my life.

Comment: @anouk In that case, omit both words and simply say "*my hair is wet because I washed it*". But as soon as you include either "just" or "still" it makes the sentence about timing and so you have to consider more carefully what you are saying.

Comment: My hair is wet because I washed it means I washed it recently and not sometime in my life. Am I right? That is all I need to know. –

Comment: @anouk One would assume that, knowing how long hair takes to dry and the fact your hair *is* wet meaning that it is *currently* wet. But it is not explicit in your sentence and the language does not *mean* that, no. If you said "I have a million dollars because I won the lottery" it would not mean you *just* won it recently.

Comment: If my hair is wet now because I washed it,it is a direct result from the washing. If the washing took place last month my hair wouldn't be wet now as a direct result, would it?

Comment: @anouk Yes but this is an English learners site, not a science site. We are not here to debate how long it takes wet hair to dry. You are asking what the *language* means, and I'm telling you. Yes it *implies* you washed it recently, but only if your audience knows how long hair takes to dry. Here's another example: "My hair is red because I dyed it". Does this mean you *just* dyed it? No. How long does hair dye last? I for one have no idea. Someone else might know, and that might give them an idea of how recently you dyed it, but others wouldn't have a clue.